# Extract total number of posts from a specific tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category, I want to show in my sidebar with the total number of posts(how many posts this category has).

Comment: Where is the code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/

Or if you like code yourself. Here it is:
You can use the method [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for getting result which accepts single array parameter or string parameter as given below.

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&category=4'); 
$count = count($posts); 
echo $count; 
?>
```

Explanation for above code:
It fetches posts result from the table `wp_posts` whose `post_type` is `post` and belongs to the `category` id `4`. Then we used php function `count` for getting total records.

If you need only published posts additionally add `post_status=publish`.

```
function wpb_postsbycategory() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'announcements', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); 

$posts = get_posts('post_type=post&category_name=announcements'); 
$count = count($posts); 

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= "<p>Total:<strong>{$count}</strong></p>";
    $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            } else { 
            // if no featured image is found
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            }
            }
    } else {
    // no posts found
}
$string .= '</ul>';

return $string;

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');

// Enable shortcodes in text widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

By using the above function you can produce the resultant output. (for reference [Show recent posts by category](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-show-recent-posts-by-category-in-wordpress/)

Simply visit `Appearance » Widgets` menu and add a `text widget` to your `sidebar`. Next add `[categoryposts]` shortcode in the text widget and save it.

Comment: hi @gvgvgvijayan  `<?php $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&category=4'); 
$count = count($posts); 
echo $count; 
?>` how do I display the number of posts in the current category, current category ID, instead of a specific category ID?

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247859/how-to-get-category-id-of-current-post

Comment: thanks friend for reply :-) I found something yesterday: `<?php $category = get_the_category(); 
echo '('.$category[0]->category_count.' posts)';  ?>`  thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

To count total number of post of a specific category this method can be used.

```
<?php
        function count_cat_post($category) {
          //you can pass name of the category such as 'js'
          if(is_string($category)) {
              $catID = get_cat_ID($category);
          }
          //you can also pass id of the category
          elseif(is_numeric($category)) {
            $catID = $category;
          } else {
            return 0;
        }
        $cat = get_category($catID);
        return $cat->count;
        }
    //finally call the function
    count_cat_post('js');//or pass the category id as argument
    ?>
```